# Visual Studio 2022 Professional: How can I get Web GUI apllication for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using visual studio 2022 professional edition and I need to get Web GUI Application for migrate windows form app to web.

I know previous editions e.g. visual studio 2010 had Visual web GUI application. But visual studio 2022 professional not.

In this case. How can I download Visual Web GUI for using web Gui application for visual studio 2022 professional? Should I go visual studio installer - click on modify and which individual component must I install? Or I have to install any extension for web gui application?

In the worst case. How Can I do to migrating a windows form app to web using microsoft visual studio 2022 professional edition if there isn't any extension nor individual component for web gui application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in 2010 I'm guessing you used "ASP.NET Webforms". It was a way for desktop developers to easier get into web development by allowing a familiar workflow with WYSIWYG and components you could drag onto your "form". This is old technology these days however and I would not recommend building anything new on it today.

It is supported in VS2022 though, you just need to add the component **".NET Framework project and item templates"** and then create a new **"ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)"**.

[image: Visual Studio Installer window showing the required component]

It isn't as simple as clicking on "migrate" on your old application though. It will need to be reimplemented (and depending on what your application does, it might require a lot of custom components and frontend scripts). It is talked about a bit in this answer: [Is it possible to convert a WinForm to a WebForm in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379130/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-winform-to-a-webform-in-net)

I would suggest that you look into newer technologies though, such as ASP.Net Core or maybe Blazor instead of investing a lot of time in converting to webforms.